# How do I sign into Chrome while keeping my local account setup?

Tags: google-chrome

I have somehow managed to (deliberately) avoid signing into Chrome since getting my current desktop computer, even while signing into Gmail.

But now I'm ready to surrender, so I can sync it with a new laptop.

However, when I sign into Chrome with my Google account, all my current extensions and bookmarks from this local account are lost. Is there a way to keep them?